# Not able to add record to mongodb using express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create an user in MongoDb using express Route. I am hitting the endpoint but there is no response from the server. I am using other endpoints server woks correctly. Kindly help me understand the error.

```
Route file:
const express = require('express');
const midasCommonController = require('../controllers/midasCommonController');

const router =  express.Router();

router.route('/').post(midasCommonController.createProfile);


module.exports = router;
```

```
controller file:
exports.createProfile  = (req,res) =>{

    console.log(req.query);
    const segment = req.query.segment;
    if(segment==="User"){
        factory.createOne(User)
    }
}
```

```
Factory functions:
exports.createOne = Model =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      console.log("I am in createone")
    const doc = await Model.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc
      }
    });
  });
```

```
End point that I am hitting:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/midasCommon?segment=User
```

Comment: Does this logs console.log(req.query);?

Comment: Hi Prabhjot,It returns { segment: 'User' }

Comment: Also why are you using this ===?? Do you want to compare datatype also?

Comment: I have two different models in mongodb , i am trying to select the "Model" using query parameter.

Comment: Kindly use == equality operator instead of strict equality operator ===.

Comment: Not sure of data type I want to check for a string if it matches to model name.

Comment: Hi, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just update this code:

```
if(segment=="User"){
        factory.createOne(User)
    }
```

The ‘==’ operator tests for abstract equality i.e. it does the necessary type conversions before doing the equality comparison.
But the ‘===’ operator tests for strict equality i.e it will not do the type conversion hence if the two values are not of the same type, when compared, it will return false.

Comment: HI Prabhjot, sorry but still facing the issue. Other routes on server work as expectred

Comment: No..That is not firing..Code hangs at hello from the middleware
{ segment: 'User' }

Comment: Try this to catch the error try{ factory.createOne(User)'} catch(err){console.log(error)}.

Comment: sure give me 2 mins

Comment: when I call this function without conditions it works..There is nothing on console

Comment: I think the issue is with the facory.createone it does not get called as If condition is returning true as result.

Comment: Is there is any specific code that needs to written for parameterized POST request